# Should I use "moving in to" or "moving into" for this sentence?

Tags: grammar

While writing a sentence like this one, should I use "moving in to" or "moving into"? Since "move in" seems to be a phrasal verb, is it safe to assume that the right choice would be "moving in to"?

They invited all their friends to celebrate their moving in to Crimson Park.

Comment: Presumably your confusion arises from the fact that ***to move in*** is a "phrasal verb" (having the *specific* meaning *take up residence in a new home*). To avoid the awkwardness of repeating ***in*** to reference the *location*, I'd probably opt for *...to celebrate their moving in **at** Crimson Park*. Using ***into*** there would be possible, but loses the phrasal verb element.

Comment: @FF No; we've had this one before. There are two 'phrasal verbs' (better, MWVs): intransitive 'move in' and transitive 'move into'. {[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/move+in)}